# Replacing a single occurrence of string Obj-c

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, replace, nsstring

I am trying to replace only one of the occurrences of a NSString with another string.  I know that you can use **stringByReplacing**Occurrences**OfString**; however, that replaces all occurrences.  What I am looking for is more like **stringByReplacing**Occurrence**OfString**.  If anyone could help me that would be great.  Thanks,
Jnani

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
NSRange location = [someString rangeOfString:stringToReplace];
NSString* result = [someString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:location withString:stringToReplaceWith];
```

Comment: which is exactly what the OP asked :p

Comment: mind it brother @SVD... he asked for only one... he hasn't mentioned whether its first occurence or last or somewhere in between. :P

Comment: True, he didn't mention that... Therefore, a solution that replaces any occurrence (including the first) is a valid one ;)